# C++ WIN32: Short multitasking example

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I searched for examples on how to create a simple multithreaded app that does something similar to this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int myConcurrentFunction( )
{
    while( 1 )
    {
         cout << "b" << endl;
    }
}
int main( )
{
    // Start a new thread for myConcurrentFunction
    while( 1 )
    {
         cout << "a" << endl;
    }
}
```

- How can I get the above to output `a` and `b` "randomly" by starting a new thread instead of just calling `myConcurrentFunction` normally?

I mean: What is the minimal code for it? Is it really only one function I have to call? What files do I need to include?

I use MSVC 2010, Win32

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is [_beginthread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28VS.80%29.aspx). Just focus on how they create the thread in their example, it's not as complicated as it seems at a first glance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>

using namespace std;
void myConcurrentFunction(void *dummy)
{
    while( 1 )
    {
         cout << "b" << endl;
    }
}

int main( )
{
    _beginthread(myConcurrentFunction, 0, NULL);
    while( 1 )
    {
         cout << "a" << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is more complicated than that. For one, the thread function must return a DWORD, and  take an LPVOID parameters.

Take a look at the [code from](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453(VS.85).aspx) MSDN for more details.

Comment: yes his is much simpler. Use that one unless you are writing pure C. :D

Answer (score -2):

BTW, why thread when you just need random sprinkiling of 'a' & 'b'.

int randomSprinkling()
{
    char val[2]={'a','b'};

```
int i = 0;
while( ++i < 100  ) 
{
    std::cout << val[rand()%2] << std::endl; 
} 
return 0;
```

}

Comment: @Con Current: I don't think you need to be so mean to the answerer.

Comment: Speaking of trolling, do you often call people stupid when they try to help you? Reported your comment as offensive. Please keep in mind that this isn't a kindergarten.

Comment: @con current. I am not fastest, but practical and dislike trolls as much as you do. You can see how many points I have earned in last 1 month for the proof :-) 
Some times, people need solutions and they have some half-baked idea of doing it in a particular way only. The asker may just needed what I provided, but he thought that this could be achiieved via threads only.